# Classification of faithfully flat morphisms between formal power series

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}[[z_1,\dots,z_n]]$ denote the algebra of formal power series.
I am interested in faithfully flat morphisms 
$$Spec(\mathbb{C}[[z_1,\dots,z_m]])\to Spec(\mathbb{C}[[z_1,\dots,z_n]]),\, m\geq n$$
up to formal diffeomorphisms of the source and the target.

**Is there anything known about classification of such objects?**

Unfortunately I am unable to formulate my question more precisely.

Example. If $m=n=1$ then any such morphism is equivalent (in the above sense) to the morphism given by $z\mapsto z^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: Every local homomorphism of local rings induces a graded homomorphism of the associated graded rings.  Thus, there are "at least as many" local homomorphisms from the power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[z_1,\dots,z_n]]$ to itself as there are finite morphisms from $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{n-1}$ to itself.  Already for $n=2$, there are moduli spaces of such maps, even after forming the quotient by pre- and post-composition with $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1)$.  The dimensions of the moduli spaces increase to infinity.

Comment: I think such a morphism is automatically flat if the closed fiber has dimension $m-n$ by `miracle flatness' (Matsumura, Thm. 23.1). Also, I guess you mean continuous morphisms ($\rm Spf$ instead of $\rm Spec$), in which case 'faithfully' should be automatic. This suggests that a classification should be beyond reach in higher dimensions.